# How to distinguish "Android" from other "Linux" operating systems in Python?

Tags: android, python

I'm running a Python script on my phone through QPython. The title pretty much explains the question. I basically need to check if the script is running on an android device. I've tried `os.name`, `sys.platform` and `platform.system()` but those just return various kinds of "Linux" or "Posix", which is not specific enough (as far as I know - maybe I am missing some relevant information here).

I considered trying to import the `android` module, and then use the success or failure of this to determine if the OS is Android. I don't really need the `android` module though, so this seems a bit excessive.

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish it?

Comment: there is some code in kivy.utils that may be useful under the Platform class https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/utils.py

Comment: perhaps call `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, or `uname -r` and check against the proccesor? although not quite reliable provided that mobile processors are so powerful nowadays

Comment: @DavidZwicker The script is downloading a file and I need to know where to save it. If the script is running on Android I want it to download to '/sdcard/Download', otherwise it should download to the standard download folder in the "HOME" directory.

Comment: I don't have an android so can't check, but I detect various linux's by looking at release files. There is supposed to be an `/etc/lsb-release` file that tells you what you are on, but its not universally supported. `ls /etc/*release` may give you better file names.

Comment: @JohnnyHansen In that case, I would just save the file to /sdcard/Download if the folder exist and otherwise use the home directory.

Comment: Why not test for the existence of the android save directory and then use that to decide where to save the file.

Comment: @DavidZwicker I had not thought of that. I also did not expect it to be that difficult to determine if the OS is android, but I guess I will just check if the '/sdcard/Download' folder exists.

Comment: Well, even if the OS is android, it is not guaranteed that the `/sdcard/Download` folder exists. That's why it's better to check for the folder directly.

Comment: @DavidZwicker But then it doesn't solve my problem. If the folder doesn't exist then it should be created, if the system is Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for `'ANDROID_STORAGE'` in environ:

```
>>> from os import environ
>>> is_android = 'ANDROID_STORAGE' in environ
>>> is_android
True
```